# android viewtreeObserver load again when click on button

Tags: android, listview

I have a ViewTreeObserver and I want to click on button and reload this ListView again
this is my code of viewTreeObserver:

```
 menuLinkListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
    observer= menuLinkListView.getViewTreeObserver();
      observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
           boolean measured=false;


            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if(!measured){
                listHeight=menuLinkListView.getHeight();

              int spacing =0;
                int  itemsPerRow = 2;
                adapter=new HomeMenuLinksListArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,MyApplication.articles, listHeight);
                    wrapperAdapter = new MultiItemRowListAdapter(MainActivity.this, adapter, itemsPerRow, spacing);
                   menuLinkListView. setAdapter(wrapperAdapter);
                }
            //  observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                measured=true;
            }
        });
```

and when I click on button I want to get new articles list and reload this ListView again with new arrayList. How can I do that?

note that *MyApplication.articles = ArrayList of articles*

at on Click I call this asynk task:

```
    getArticles getarticles = new getArticles();
    getarticles.execute("2",tag);
```

the code of AsynkTask:

```
public class getArticles extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Article>>
{
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<Article> array = new ArrayList<Article>();
    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
          pd=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), false);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(String... params) {


           if(Actions.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this))
           {

           Connection.disableSSLCertificateChecking();
             String    url=getResources().getString(R.string.serviceLink)+getResources().getString(R.string.getArticleIssueCat) + "issueId=" + params[0] + "&categoryId=" + params[1]; 

            Connection conn=new Connection( url);


                ArticleXmlPullParser parser = new ArticleXmlPullParser();

                        array=parser.parse(conn.getInputStream());


           }
        return array;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Article> p)
    {
         MyApplication.articles = p;
        adapter.notidyDataSetChanged();//here i cann notify for adapter of listview but nothing changed
         try{
               pd.dismiss();
               }catch(Exception e){

               }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the way do it. Why do u need to create new adapters everytime onGlobalLayout()is called? why just not add notifiyDataChanged() at onClick()?

Comment: i just added notifyDataChanged at onClick but still showing the old arrayList

Comment: The issue with the code isnt here. Attach more code. What do u have else at the onClick()? do u download more data? add/remove? why do u need to load the list again? Attach more code and ill help u out.

Comment: okay i will put my code , in each time i click the button i want to load new data and display it on the list, i update my question with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that u didnt change the data on the adapter.
There should be a *set* method for the data at the adapter.

> MyApplication.articles = p;
>
> **adapter.setData(p);**
>
> adapter.notidyDataSetChanged();

something like this

Comment: did you mean `adapter.clear(); adapter.addAll(p); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and Its working :D .. thank you

Comment: Its been a while since i used an adapter with data and not CursorAdapter. At CursorAdapter u have a method called cursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor) this does the trick. But if clear and addAll work then it workd :)
I would have try maybe a way to update only the Delta between the articles and not all of them...